# Do you say "don't leave your sleeve pendulous, roll it up"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

> **[pendulous](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pendulous?q=pendulous)** (adj): hanging down loosely and moving from side to side

---

[image]

The sleeve seems to be a bit too long, which makes you uncomfortable.

Do you say "**don't leave your sleeve pendulous, roll it up**"?

but "**pendulous**" is not a "down to earth" adjective.

or say "**don't leave the sleeve dangled**"?

**What is the better way to express it?**

Comment: Roll up your [shirt] sleeves. Just that.

Comment: "Don't let your sleeves hang down."

Comment: @KateBunting, what about "Don't let your sleeves dangled"?

Comment: "Don't let them _dangle_". But dangling refers more to something hanging freely on its own, like a trailing string.